# Selenium Python trying to click on Radio button error ElementNotVisibleException

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I have a webpage with some radio buttons.  I am trying to click on a radio button but it is not clicking and throwing

The full error is:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Webdriver\ClearCore\TestCases\DataPreviewsPage_TestCase.py", line 48, in test_add_Lademo_CRM_DataPreviews
    data_previews_page.click_from_file_radio_button_from_options_tab()
  File "C:\Webdriver\ClearCore\Pages\data_previews.py", line 112, in click_from_file_radio_button_from_options_tab
    fromfile_radiobutton.click()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 69, in click
    self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 448, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 196, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 181, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
ElementNotVisibleException: Message: Cannot click on element
```

My method to click the button is:

```
def click_from_file_radio_button_from_options_tab(self):
        fromfile_radiobutton = self.driver.find_element(*MainPageLocators.data_previews_fields_from_File_radioButton_from_options_tab_xpath)
        fromfile_radiobutton.click()
        return self
```

The XPATH for the locator for the button from MainPageLocators is:

```
data_previews_fields_from_File_radioButton_from_options_tab_xpath = (By.XPATH, '//span[@class="gwt-RadioButton block"]/label[contains(text(), "From file")]/../input')
```

The HTML is:

```
<table class="gwt-DisclosurePanel gwt-DisclosurePanel-open" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="left" style="vertical-align: top;">
                    <div style="padding: 0px; overflow: hidden;" aria-hidden="false">
                        <div class="content" aria-hidden="false">
                            <span class="gwt-RadioButton block">
                                <input id="gwt-uid-163" type="radio" name="fields" value="on" tabindex="0" checked=""/>
                                <label for="gwt-uid-163">From file</label>
                            </span>
                            <span class="gwt-RadioButton block">
                            <span class="gwt-RadioButton GPI5XK1CET GPI5XK1CFT">
                            <input class="gwt-IntegerBox" type="text" disabled="" size="3"/>
                            <span class="gwt-RadioButton block">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

It does not show hidden=True in the HTML.  It shouldn't say Element is not visible.  I do not know why i cannot click this button.
It is visible on the webpage.

How can i click this radio button?
Some help appreciated.

Thanks,
Riaz

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe your XPath is correct. I would try something like this. I can't tell from the limited HTML if this will be unique enough or not.

```
fromfile_radiobutton = self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[type='radio'][name='fields']")
fromfile_radiobutton.click()
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  It is not unique as there are other radio buttons.  I have asked the developer to put an ID for the table.  I can then build the xpath starting from the table id.

Comment: Just for fun... try this `self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector("table.gwt-DisclosurePanel.gwt-DisclosurePanel-open input[type='radio'][name='fields']")`. I added a reference to the `TABLE` that might be unique enough to find the radio.